# SELECT REPLACE Multiple Cases of the Same Value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, replace

I know that SELECT REPLACE can replace one case of a string but I am trying to replace multiple cases with the same string and I haven't found an example of how to do this.

I have a table:

```
+--------------+
| station_name |
+--------------+
| WABC-FM      |
| WXYZ-G2      |
| WWWW-H2      |
| WWAS-A2      |
| WFRE-A3      |
| WRES-AM      |
+--------------+
```

What I'd like is a bit complicated. I'll use the normal SELECT REPLACE to try to explain what I'm looking for.

Basically, every instance of G2 or H2 needs to be replaced with FM and every intance of A2 or A3 with AM.

So something like `SELECT REPLACE(station_name, ['G2', 'H2'], 'FM')` combined with another `SELECT REPLACE(station_name, ['A2', 'A3'], 'AM')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may chain four calls to `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(station_name, 'G2', 'FM'), 'H2', 'FM'),
                    'A2', 'AM'), 'A3', 'AM')
FROM yourTable;
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, you could use `REGEXP_REPLACE`, which would only require two calls instead of four:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(station_name, '[GH]2', 'FM'), 'A[23]', 'AM')
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: I know I only gave the example of two cases for both "FM" and "AM" but there really are like 20 cases for each so I really hope 8+ is installed. Looking into REGEXP_REPLACE now. Thanks for your help! Cheers

Comment: @eeetee If you really have many replacements, then consider creating a table containing mappings from old to new.  Then, you might be able to handle this using a join.

Comment: It might not be that bad considering the regex would be `'H[23456789]'` in my case.  Same letter, but from 2 to 9. Might get away with 4 replace functions.

Comment: @eeetee Use `H[2-9]`, that is, use the range as an abbreviation.

Comment: Will do. I really appreciate your help!